# Redirect forum link from wordpress post to another page which has a template with iframe pointing to the actual forum

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iframe, mybb

Okay so... I have a wordpress post in which I have a link to my forum.

The forum is integrated with the wordpress design in an iframe. I would like to go from the article page to the forum page and open the link from the article in the forum page's iframe (in which the forum is loaded).

The forum page is /forum/ thats how wordpress displays it but actually the forum is hosted under /Forum/

I don't want people going directly to the forum without the design which is http:/ /website.com/Forum/

I hope this explains it.

Lets say I have a wordpress post with a sidebar and in the sidebar I have links to my recent forum threads for example one url:

http :// website. com/Forum/showthread.php?tid=4

I created a wordpress template page called Forum.php within which I have iframe that goes to http :// website. com/Forum/

The wordpress page which i applied the forum.php template to is http :// website. com/forum/ notice the small f.

So when you go to http://website.com/forum/ it loads the forum.php which has an iframe ID=frmid and src=http://website.com/Forum/

How would I have my links inject into http :// website. com/forum/ (forum.php iframe ID=frmid) and load properly seamlessly?

Comment: Okay I hope this helps explain it so lets say

Comment: ive spent over six hours on this crap... i finally figured out a solution and will share with others...